# How does the Carnot Cycle work?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle, efficient-energy-use

I am learning the Carnot cycle, which consists of four transformations for a fluid.

In the **first two transformations** the volume of the fluid expands, generating work.

This happens in two steps:

1. First, we approach a hot source and the gas expands and work is generated (okay, temperature increases and fluid wants to expand → the generated work comes 100% from the consumed heat, because the internal energy did not change during the isothermal process)
2. Then we remove the hot source and the gas is supposed to keep expanding (**Question A**: Not really sure how the gas keeps expanding after we remove the hot source. If no heat source is close, it seems logic to expect that the expansion will just stop. Why would it want to continue? Expansion means work done. Since there is no heat flow, the gas would be losing internal energy. Why would the gas want to lose internal energy to create work?).

In the **second two transformations** the volume of the fluid decreases.

This happens in two steps:

3. First, we approach a cold source, so the fluid naturally flushes some heat away to the cold source and hence decreases its temperature and hence decreases its volume. (That is quite reasonable).
4. Finally, the fluid keeps compressing, automatically increasing its temperature and pressure, coming back to state number 1 (**Question B**: How can expect the fluid to keep being compressed automatically? Being this an adiabatic process and an increase in temperature, this means work must be done on the system. Who is doing this work?).

**1** and **3** are based on putting a thermal source close to the fluid so nature will do what it does, according to the second law.

But **2** and **4** seem like magic to me, since I don't understand what goes on behind the scenes.

There is a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192499/understanding-the-carnot-cycle) but I still don't get it. Thought it was better to create a new question, rather than commenting on an old one. Also, this way I can expose my complete point of view on the case.

I would also like to understand how this relates to the efficiency of the carnot cycle.

Which comes from something like:

$$\dfrac{GeneratedWork}{GivenEnergy}=\dfrac{HeatIn-HeatOut}{HeatIn}$$

This is understandable but then it goes on like:

$$\dfrac{HeatIn-HeatOut}{HeatIn} = 1 - \dfrac{T_{cold}}{T_{hot}}$$

There are two confusions with this:

**Question C**.

How is it possible to mix **heat** and **temperature** in such an easy way?

This is almost like saying that heat = temperature.

Also, I understood heat is never absolute, but a variation. While temperature is actually an absolute measure.

**Question D**.

If 4 actually requires external work for the compression, how come is this applied work not reflected in the efficiency? (maybe it is, but I do not see it)

**UPDATE**:

This video is very helpful: [https://youtu.be/d6eJ8mccvu0&t=939](https://youtu.be/d6eJ8mccvu0)

Comment: In (adiabatic) step 2, imagine that you have a vertical cylinder with a piston, and a bunch of small weights is sitting on top of the piston.  As you gradually remove weights from the piston, the gas expands and the piston rises.  This results in work being done to raise the remainder of the weights that are still on the piston.  Step 4 is the opposite of this.  In both cases, work is done to raise the weights, and the gas expands without heat being added.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks, but, "In both cases, work is done to raise the weights" --> Who or what is doing that work? So the cycle is just the idea, but someone must find a way for that work to be done. How then, is that work applied to the system  considered in the efficiency? I only see net work, but not the applied work. And... I think it is okay to think it will be more or less work depending on how you create the real machine. This is considering an ideal process, but still, it is not stating where that work comes from. The "As you gradually remove weights from the piston". Who is doing this?

Comment: Oops.  I mis-stated.  In step 4, adding the weights does work on the gas, as the piston get lower.  Also, please understand that the work done by the gas in step 2 exactly matches the work done on the gas in step 4.  So,, there is no net work done is steps 2 and 4.

Comment: @ChetMiller I cannot see that work being done is the same since we take the same amount of stuff from state 2 to 3, and then from 4 to 1. All of them have different internal energy, so... how can they be the same? Also, I don't understand why at step 2 the fluid would want to expand. If there is no heat transfer, why would the gas expand at all? I expect it to just stay there. What makes it expand?

Comment: Taking the weight off the piston lowers the applied pressure from the outside and causes it to expand.  The net work is done in steps 1 and 3.  Actually, just see @Bob D's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical depiction of the Carnot Cycle is with the use of a closed cylinder containing an ideal gas fitted with a piston with a shaft that extends outside the cylinder to interact with the surroundings. In the following I will refer to the fluid as an ideal gas.

> First, we approach a hot source (okay, temperature increases and fluid
>   wants to expand)

The first process is reversible isothermal (constant temperature) expansion. The temperature does not increase. For an ideal gas that means the product of the pressure and volume is constant. As the volume expands the pressure resisting the expansion  by the surroundings must proportionately decrease. The work done in the expansion exactly equals the heat added and the change in internal energy is zero. By the first law $\Delta U=Q-W$. Since $\Delta U=0$, we have $Q=W$ and $Q=T_{HOT}\Delta S$ where $\Delta S$ is the change in entropy.

> Then we remove the hot source (Question A: Not really sure how the
>   fluid keeps expanding after we remove the hot source. If no heat
>   source is close, it seems logic to expect that the expansion will just
>   stop.).

The second process is a reversible adiabatic (no heat transfer) process. The answer to question A is the gas keeps expanding because the external pressure is gradually intentionally reduced to allow the expansion to continue. Since $Q=0$ the work done in the expansion is at the expense of the internal energy, $\Delta U=- W$. Note that $W$ is considered positive when the gas does work on the surroundings (expands).

> First, we approach a cold source, so the fluid naturally flushes some
>   heat away to the cold source and hence decreases it's temperature and
>   hence decreases its volume.

The third process is a reversible isothermal (constant temperature) compression. This is the same as the first process in reverse. In this case surroundings does work on the gas equal to the heat transfer out of the out of the gas to the surroundings.

> Finally, the fluid keeps compressing, automatically increasing its
>   temperature and pressure, coming back to state number 1 (Question B:
>   How can expect the fluid to keep being compressed automatically?).

The fourth and final process is a reversible adiabatic compression. It is the same as the second process only in reverse such that work is done on the gas by the surroundings as opposed to the gas doing work on the surroundings. The answer to question B is the gas is not compressed "automatically". An external agent in the surroundings exerts pressure slightly greater than the gas pressure in order to compress the gas.

> But 2 and 4 seem like magic to me, since I don't understand what goes
>   on behind the scenes.

Think about the cycle being performed by a piston and cylinder with the piston shaft connected to something outside the cylinder. Basically, what goes on behind the scenes, which is outside the cylinder, is an external agent (the surroundings) is either exerting a pressure on the gas slightly greater than the pressure of the gas in order to compress the gas (process 4) or exerts a pressure slightly less than the pressure of the gas allowing it to expand (process 2). It is important to note that the positive work done by the gas in process 2 exactly equals the  negative  work done on the gas in process 4, so the net work done for the two processes is zero.

For processes 1 and 3 the pressure exerted by the external agent also accommodates the expansion or compression of the gas. But in these cases it does so in such a way that the temperature of the gas remains constant.

> Question C.
>
> How is it possible to mix heat and temperature in such an easy way?
>
> This is almost like saying that heat = temperature.

In equating the efficiency on the left with the relationship of temperatures on the right you are leaving out the important in between steps.

The net work generated is

$$W_{net}=Q_{IN}-Q_{OUT}$$

This equates energy terms. Then for the two isothermal processes, where $\Delta S$ is the change in entropy, we have the following:

$$Q_{IN}=T_{HOT}\Delta S$$

$$Q_{OUT}=T_{COLD}\Delta S$$

Efficiency is give by

$$ϒ=\frac{Q_{IN}-Q_{OUT}}{Q_{IN}}$$

Substituting we have

$$ϒ=\frac{T_{HOT}\Delta S-T_{COLD}\Delta S}{T_{HOT}\Delta S}$$

Which simplifies to

$$ϒ=1-\frac{T_{COLD}}{T_{HOT}}$$

> Question D.
>
> If 4 actually requires external work for the compression, how come is
>   this applied work not reflected in the efficiency? (maybe it is, but I
>   do not see it)

As indicated above, the adiabatic compression work done on the gas in process 4 exactly equals the adiabatic expansion work done by the gas in process 2. That means they cancel out and are not part of the efficiency calculation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bob D. This is just perfect. Really appreciate the fact that a stranger teaches clearer than paid teachers at Universities. Sure this helps, not only me, but other future readers too. Thanks. I have been thinking about "the positive work done by the gas in process 2 exactly equals the negative work done on the gas in process 4" but I do not understand why this is true. We are working with the same temperature changes in both processes, but the volume and pressure involved are different. Being work the total pdV changes, how can I clearly see that both amounts are equal?

Comment: @AlvaroFranz Glad it was helpful. Regarding 2 and 4 you are  right we are dealing with the same temperature changes. But for an ideal gas, the change in internal energy depends ONLY on the temperature change and is given by, for any process, $\Delta U=C_{v}\Delta T$. Since for the adiabatic process $\Delta U=-W$ that means the magnitude of $W$ will be the same for both processes, but the sign will be different and therefore the two works cancel. Hope this clarifies for you.

Comment: This is beyond clear. Genius.

Comment: Bob, sorry I re-awake this thing. But just one more consideration. For process two you say.... "because the external pressure is gradually intentionally reduced" but then consider that as work done by the system. If someone/something reduces the pressure intentionally, that someone/something will have put in the work for the expansion, maybe pulling from outside so the gas has more space inside its working container. What I mean is, it's not the gas itself spontaneously expanding. Some external thing is helping it to have more space by freeing that space by "pulling" the thing to make space.

Comment: @AlvaroFranz No problem. For one thing, in order for the isothermal expansion to be carried out reversibly it has to be carried out extremely slowly (quasi-statically). If there were no external resistance to the expansion it would occur expand rapidly. A rapid expansion causes irreversibility (entropy generation) and a reduction in efficiency. By keeping the external pressure slightly less than the gas pressure , it expands slowly and work is still done. The disadvantage to the reversible cycle is the work is done very slowly (very low power), even though it is the most efficient.

Comment: I understand Carnot designed it supposed to be carried out quasi-statically, being it the supreme ideal version with no efficiency loss. But I still cannot see who or what is doing this infinitesimal pressure lowerings, or... better said, I cannot see that the gas will be responsible for that work. Instead, I see that infinitesimal compressions from 4 to 1 are indeed external work. Maybe, since everything is just an idea, we are supposing the gas will have micro expansions just because it has no apparent change and just because nobody is opposing to that. But... why would that happen at all?

Comment: @AlvaroFranz First you need to understand no one actually uses a heat engine with a Carnot Cycle. Someone once said is you put a Carnot engine in your car you would get fantastic gas mileage, but pedestrians would be passing you by. It is an idealization to show what the maximum possible efficiency of a heat engine could be. That said, you can dream up what the external agent is. Chester Miller gave you an example with tiny weights (e.g., grains of sand) placed on top of a weightless piston.

Comment: When you remove the weights one at a time the gas expands a tiny bit elevating the remaining weights a tiny bit. Since the remaining weights are raised, a tiny bit of work is done by the gas that increases the potential energy of the remaining weights. When you add weights one at a time the gas compresses a tiny bit lowering the remaining weights and compressing the gas. The remaining weights do a tiny bit of work on the gas equal to the drop in potential energy of the remaining weights.

Comment: None of this is intended to represent anything practical. As I said the cycle is an idealization that gives you the maximum possible for a heat engine. Kind of a benchmark to compare practical cycles to.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Knowing "thanks" should be avoided. Must say it. Thank you a lot. Have a nice day, every remaining day!

Comment: @AlvaroFranz You too.

Comment: @Nico Brenner I approved your edit, but I certainly didn't intend to "belittle" the OP. You can see from the OP's comments it wasn't taken that way.

Comment: FYI I don't think it's "belittling" to point out that they are misunderstanding the cycle.    I think "You are having difficulty because it appears you don't understand the processes of the Carnot Cycle." would be a lot more useful than removing that line completely (I was rejecting the edit but you approved it while I had the review open).

Comment: @JMac Thanks and I agree with you. Just didn't want to make a big deal about it. Regards,

Comment: Thank you BobD and @JMac for your quick and effective review of the edit. Unfortunately, written text is subject to widely varying interpretation. From my perspective as a reader, the first sentence read badly and seemed like the answer didn't really need it. Now I understand that the intention I interpreted wasn't there in the first place.

Comment: @NicoBrenner No problem. No harm done.

Comment: Beyond the fact that this "little" considerations are not relevant, it makes this knowledge-exchange place the most amazing knowledge-exchange place I know. How about this model extrapolated to politics, where everyone peacefully participates... cheers!